# How do I make the Score in my game to work with int parameter instead of float?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making 2D runner game in unity, and I wrote some code with the help of a few tutorials, but here is the problem, **The score in my game starting from 0.08 and jumping by 4, for example 0.12, 0.16 etc.**
**How do I make it so that it increases by 1 and a whole number?**
Would appreciate help.

(Its the shortened version of the code, if you need the full one let me know.)

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    **float score;

    bool IsAlive = true;

    public Text ScoreTxt;**


    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) 
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("ground"))
        {
           ** if(IsAlive)
            {
                score += Time.deltaTime * 4; 
                ScoreTxt.text = "Score: " + score.ToString("F");
            }**
        }
    

        if(collision.gameObject.CompareTag("obstacle"))
        {
            IsAlive = false;
            Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried to use int parameter instead of float but the compiler gave me this error: error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'float' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2):

I assume the idea is to increase the score by four points per second. The error you get is because `deltaTime` is a float. The easiest fix is to just change the printout:

```
"Score: " + (int)score; // Truncates
```

or

```
"Score: " + score.ToString("F0"); // Rounds
```

Comment: and where do i put it? or replace?

Comment: @R1vel Replace your current line, starting with `"Score"`

Comment: Here?:

  if(IsAlive)
            {
                **score += Time.deltaTime * 4;**
                **ScoreTxt.text = "Score: " + score.ToString("F");**
            }

Comment: @R1vel If this is a problem for you, just replace `"F"` with `"F0"` and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Mathf.CeilToInt()**.

```c#
// Prints 10
Debug.Log(Mathf.CeilToInt(10.0f));
// Prints 11
Debug.Log(Mathf.CeilToInt(10.2f));
// Prints 11
Debug.Log(Mathf.CeilToInt(10.7f));
```

for example:

```C#
...
if(IsAlive)
{
  score += Time.deltaTime * 4f; 
  score = Mathf.CeilToInt(score);
  ScoreTxt.text = "Score: " + score.ToString();
}
...
```